# Understanding Example 12 All Permutations of a string from Big O notation - Cracking the Coding Interview

Tags: java, big-o

I'm stuck understanding how the author got the complexity of `O(n^2 * n!)`  of the following procedure which generates all permutation of a string.

```
void permutation(String str){
   permutation(str,"");
}
void permutation(String str, String prefix){
  if(str.length()==0){
    System.out.println(prefix);
  } else{
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
        String rem=str.substring(0,i)+str.substring(i+1);
         permutation(rem,prefix+str.charAt(i));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The complexity of the method is `O(n^2 *n!)` because of the else path cost:

First notice that each call to `String rem=str.substring(0,i)+str.substring(i+1);` is `O(n)`,
 in the `else` path we compute it `n` times together with a call to `permutation` which has complexity `T(n-1)`.

Computing the complexity of this is equivalent to solving: `T(n) = n[n+T(n-1)]`; `n` times (the for loop) a work of `(n+T(n-1))`

Solving this recurrence is not that easy, If I'm not wrong it should boil down to solving:

[image: foo+bar]

But let's try to approximate.
Each permutation (base case) represent a node in the recursion tree. This tree has `n!` leaf. Each leaf has a path to the root of length `n`. So It is safe to assume there are not more than `n*n!` nodes in the tree.

This is an upper bound on the number of calls to `permutation`. Since each of this call costs `n` then the overall upper bound on the complexity is `O(n^2*n!)`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Shouldn't n! drown out n^2 leaving just O(n!)? (since n! is the highest growth term)

Comment: Using the same line of reasoning then merge sort should be O(n) cause n grows faster than log n

Answer (score 4):

I'm late to the party but nonetheless I will still post my answer.

This is how I explained it to myself.
Taking a simplified approach, lets ignore all the steps of the function: `permutation(String str, String prefix)` except the recursive step.

Keeping above in mind, the time complexity of the function can be stated in terms of recurrence relation: `T(N) = N*T(N-1)`, where `N` is the length of the input string.
Upon expansion, `T(N) = N*(N-1)*(N-2)*...3*2*1*T(0)`. --- (*)

Now, `T(0) = O(N)` because in base case we are printing the prefix string, and printing a string of length N is an O(N) operation.

Expressing (*) above in closed form: `N*N!` --- (1)

Now consider the following line of the`permutation` function:
`String rem = str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i + 1);`

This is again `O(N)` operation and this is done for each of the `N!` recursive calls.
Therefore considering above and taking product with the expression (1) above, the total runtime complexity `T(N)` turns out to be

`N*N*N! = N^2*N!`

Comment: why "product with the expression (1)" and not addition?

Comment: As I've already mentioned, O(N) operations are performed for each of the N! recursive calls. So when you do 'x' things 'y' times each, they multiply and not add. Here O(N) is 'x' and N! is 'y'.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Why in the book does it say that O(n * n * n!) can be expressed as O((n + 2)!)   ?    I have plugged in a few numbers, and those two expressions are not mathematically equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

A simple trick to solve this one is O(number of nodes * computation in each node).

computation in each node is O(n).

Number of nodes can be calculated by summing nodes at each level.

i.e. (n! / 1!) + (n! / 2!) + (n! / 3!) ... + (n! / n!)

which equals n! * (1/1! + 1/2! + ... + 1/n!)

The sum of this series (1/1! + 1/2! + ... + 1/n!) was considered as **n** (as an upper bound)

Which lead to make the number of nodes to be n * n!

So, O(number of nodes * computation in each node) is O( n * n! * n)
which is **O(n<sup>2</sup> * n!)**

---

But, if we do real math, (1/1! + 1/2! + ... + 1/n!) is 1.7182 ( where n is > 6 )

So, the number of nodes are 1.7182 * n!.
The complexity must be O(1.7182 * n! * n) which is **O(n * n!)**

---

Answer (score 1):

The time complexity comes from how many times the for loop is executed. In the book this is represented by `n * n!` which is a simplification. This runtime comes from estimated number of nodes in the graph. If you start drawing up the graph you would see that the number of the nodes in the lowest level is `n!` and in each level up it is the number of nodes in the lower level divided by `2, 3, .., n` util the top level has a single node.

In the book instead of counting exact number of the nodes they multiply number of levels in the graph by the max no of branches in the level so `n * n!`. This number will always be higher or equal to the exact number of nodes so it works well as the upper bound.

Then as stated in the book the String concatenation within the for loop body will take `O(n)` so overall time complexity is `O(n * n * n!) = O(n^2 * n!)`

We do not add the time complexity taken by if body for two reasons. One is that the time complexity for the body is `O(1)` - since it is just a print statement. If the body would be dependant on n or other relevant variable then we would have to add the multiplication of that invariant and number of times the if body is executed. Secondly the if body is executed `n!` times, but we have that already accounted for in the number of for loop body executions (see the equation below for exact number of invocations of for loop body).

If we would have more lines of code in the else statement but outside of the for loop, we would have to add to the time complexity by multiplying the invariant and the number of times the else loop was executed.

I believe that we can get the exact number of nodes in the graph using equation below:

[image]

Then number of the for loop body invocations can be determined with:

[image]

We must add n! as the for loop is additionally executed n! times for rem of length zero. We must subtract 1 because for loop body is not executed for the first node (where `rem.length() == str.length()`).

Answer (score 0):

When i used the count in between the code , i always got n factorial as number of steps.

```
public class example12 {
    int count=0;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        example12 a= new example12();
        a.permutation("12345678", "test");
    }

    void permutation(String str){
           permutation(str,"");
        }

        void permutation(String str, String prefix){
          if(str.length()==0){
            System.out.println(prefix);
            System.out.println(count+"at  print");

          } else{
            for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
                String rem=str.substring(0,i)+str.substring(i+1);
                permutation(rem,prefix+str.charAt(i));
                System.out.println(count);
                count= count+1;

            }
          }
        }

}
```

Comment: you have to increase the count before if statement to know how many times permutation() is called. That would be n * n!